# How to type useFirestore() using TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using this [useFirestore()](https://vueuse.org/firebase/usefirestore/) wrapper provided by VueUse.org

But when typing `useFirestore()` with a generic I cannot use an interface that has optional properties because TypeScript throws this error:

> No overload matches this call

In the examples below the `User` interface has a required `name` property which causes typescript to throw the error.

```TypeScript
interface User {
  id?: string;
  name: string; // <-- When this property is required the error will show, changing it to optional removes the error
}

const userQuery = doc(db, 'users', 'my-user-id');
const userData = useFirestore<User>(userQuery); // <-- The error shows here on "userQuery"
```

I have found one workaround, but it's not great.

You can use `useFirestore(userQuery) as Ref<User>` which removes the error and gives it the correct type.

But doing this is not a good solution because I'm basically telling the compiler "I know better" than what the compiler is saying. So it would be much better to have proper typing without resorting to this workaround.

```TypeScript
interface User {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}

const userQuery = doc(db, 'users', 'my-user-id');
const userData = useFirestore(userQuery) as Ref<User>; // <-- See changes made here
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what is the `doc` function and what type does `useDocRef` have?

Comment: @TobiasS. `doc` is a Firestore function for getting a document refference. `userDocRef` has a type of `DocumentReference<DocumentData>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

First of all, the reason for the error is because `userQuery` was typed as `DocumentReference<DocumentData>` but `useFirestore<User>(userQuery)` was expecting `DocumentReference<User>`. Since those two types did not match the error was shown.

To get around this there are two options:

**OPTION 1:**

As shown the original question you can *coerce* the return value of `useFirestore()` like so:

```TypeScript
const userQuery = doc(db, 'users', 'my-user-id');
const userData = useFirestore(userQuery) as Ref<User>;
```

While this works, it has some drawbacks:

1. It overrides the compiler. I'm basically telling it "I know the return value is something different, but I know better, and I know it exists, so use mine instead". This can cause unforeseen problems down the road.
2. If I pass a collection query it needs to be typed as an array (`useFirestore(colQuery) as Ref<User[]>`) and if I pass a document reference it needs to be typed without the array (`useFirestore(docRef) as Ref<User>`). Forgetting this can cause other errors.
3. When using `as` you are saying "this thing *exists* and it has this type". But since `useFirestore` is async sometimes that data does not exist because it is still loading. Therefore it should also have a type of `null` or `undefined`. So actually it would better to use `useFirestore(userQuery) as Ref<User | null | undefined>` which you have to remember to do each time or you may cause issues trying to access some data that doesn't yet exist.

All this is to say I think it's better to correctly type the Firestore document reference (or collection reference) and then let `useFirestore()` return the correct types without any coercion that could create unforeseen problems.

Which brings us to option 2...

**OPTION 2:**

In my opinion this is the superior choice.

I discovered in [this medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/using-firestore-with-typescript-65bd2a602945) how to use Firestore `withConverter()` to convert data coming to and from Firestore into custom defined objects (i.e. TypeScript interfaces and classes).

If you prefer just to get straight to the code then [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/JamieCurnow/cba3968a7f1e335d473632f9fc9f6e8b) has everything you need.

But that solution is for Firebase JavaScript Version 8 SDK. And I am using the Firebase Modular JavaScript Version 9 SDK, which requires some tweaking as shown in my [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486413/how-to-create-a-typescript-generic-converter-for-firestore-withconverter).

In short - `withConverter` can be used on the end of Firestore `doc` or `collection` methods to correctly type them. It takes a single `converter` argument. And what we have created below is a re-usable "generic converter" that takes an Interface of your choice.

So you put `.withConverter(converter<MyInterfaceHere>())` on the end of `collection` or `doc` and voila! You have type safety!

Here is the full example:

```TypeScript
interface User {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}

const converter = <T>() => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T,
});

const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', 'my-user-id').withConverter(
  converter<User>()
);
const userData = useFirestore(userDocRef);
```

Now `userData` has a type of `Ref<User | null | undefined>` and you can access all the `User` properties on it without error.

It's Firestore with all the type safety you love from TypeScript!