# How to create a TypeScript generic converter for Firestore withConverter()?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firebase JavaScript Version 9 SDK.

And I'm trying to use [withConverter()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter) to cast data coming to and from Firestore with TypeScript interfaces.

There is an article [here](https://medium.com/swlh/using-firestore-with-typescript-65bd2a602945) that explains how to do it using a generic converter. It allows you to create one generic converter and re-use that instead of creating new converter logic for each Interface. Here is a [GIST with all the code from the article](https://gist.github.com/JamieCurnow/cba3968a7f1e335d473632f9fc9f6e8b) and comments explaining it well.

And here is my attempt at implementing that generic converter:

```TypeScript
interface User {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}

const converter = <T>() => ({
  toFirestore: (data: Partial<T>) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snap: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) =>
    snap.data() as T,
});

const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', 'my-user-id').withConverter(
  converter<User>() // <-- Error here
);
```

But I am getting this TypeScript error on `converter<User>()` saying this:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(converter: null): DocumentReference<DocumentData>', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(converter: FirestoreDataConverter<User>): DocumentReference<User>', gave the following error. ts(2769)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

When looking at [this help doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter) I found the correct converter types for Version 9 SDK were `PartialWithFieldValue` and `QueryDocumentSnapshot`.

Here is the full correct code:

```
interface User {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}

const converter = <T>() => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T,
});

const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', 'my-user-id').withConverter(
  converter<User>()
);
```

Now `userDocRef` has a type of `DocumentReference<User>`.

Comment: With version 11 of the admin SDK, I had to change it slightly because the PartialFieldWithValue can be null (which seems silly, but that's how it is):

`
toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data ?? {},
`