# No overload matches this call. useFirestore while defining type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vueuse

This is my code in vue3. I am learning typescript. the typescript intellisense is giving me the error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(maybeDocRef: MaybeRef<Falsy | DocumentReference<Player[]>>, initialValue?: Player[] | null | undefined, options?: UseFirestoreOptions | undefined): Ref<...>', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(maybeDocRef: MaybeRef<Falsy | Query<Player[]>>, initialValue?: Player[][] | undefined, options?: UseFirestoreOptions | undefined): Ref<...>', gave the following error.ts(2769)
```

if I remove the type from `const players = useFirestore(playersQuery);` like this, the error in intelliscense is removed how would I add the type here?

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, unref } from "vue";
import { useConfig } from "@/composables/useConfig";
import { db } from "@/util/firebase";

import { useFirestore } from "@vueuse/firebase";
import { collection, query, limit, where, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";

import type { Player } from "@/types";

const { series } = useConfig();

const playersQuery = computed(() =>
  query(
    collection(db, "players"),
    where("series", "==", unref(series)),
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
    limit(7)
  )
);
const players = useFirestore<Player[]>(playersQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74456704/how-to-type-usefirestore-using-typescript-interfaces